# auto eager loading is not working any more in EF6

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I don't know about reason, auto eager loading is not working suddenly on middle of project.
so I should write "Include" statement to all statement with relationship.
How can i set the auto eager loading again?

Comment: There's no such thing. You always had to use `Include` to eagerly load related objects that aren't directly used in the `select` expression. Most likely, the queries changed and no longer reference the related entities

Comment: You'll have to post your code for more help: DbContext configuration, entities, queries. One can only guess what changed in the code. If you use version control you could check the differences from one version to another to find what changed